# High CPU Usage When Opening Anything

Tags: 14.04, cpu, temperature

I know that my CPU isn't the great, but it seems to be getting progressively worse. When opening an application the CPU % goes to 99% - 100%. Running a Java Application goes to about 40% and opening a webpage goes from 20-80% CPU usage on any website. It loads quite fast, but I guess that is because I have an SSD.

Is the CPU on the way out or should I change the thermal paste? The temperature doesn't get that high, it is idle at about 35-40 and under load it goes to about 55c.

[Picture of specs.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWDA3.png)

Comment: A high CPU usage in itself is not bad.  Do you experience performance as slow? Is your CPU governor already set to performance, `sudo cpufreq-set -g performance`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlikely this is a CPU overheating issue.  However, if you can find an inexpensive, faster/more cores used CPU that your mobo supports you could well see a performance bump.  You already have a good amount of RAM and an SSD so there probably isn't a lot more you can do to tweak out a little more performance on that old platform.

It's a fact that with each software advance, legacy computers just get that much slower.  So long as web pages are loading quickly and the response is generally good, I wouldn't worry that much about pegging the CPU.  Obviously, your hardware is nearing the end of it's useful life but kudos for milking as much utility out of your old gear as you can.

Comment: It is not a fact. Of course games become more demanding as hw advances. But it's not true with regard to a usual apps. Why would e.g. GTK4 devs started using Vulkan, if not because they care of performance? In general, as someone reading dev. news on Phoronix, I see no tendency to worsening the performance, quite the opposite. NB: I don't know what's the problem with @Sinnska's computer, but I'd recommend to upgrade the system at least to the next LTS.